# Range() returning different output than "list" in "for" loop

Tags: python, loops, range

I'm a beginner trying to understand why I get a different output when I use the range function. If I use (len(arr)) the output: 5 0 3  vs using arr the output: 3 2 1

```
 arr = [-4, 3, -9, 0, 4, 1]
 
 def plusMinus(arr):
    count_pos = 0
    count_neg = 0
    count_zero = 0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if i>0:
        count_pos += 1
        if i<0:
        count_neg += 1
    else: 
        count_zero += 1
    print(count_pos)
    print(count_neg)
    print(count_zero)
```

Comparing that version to not using range() and just arr:

```
def plusMinus(arr):
    count_pos = 0
    count_neg = 0
    count_zero = 0
    for i in arr:
        if i>0:
        count_pos += 1
        if i<0:
        count_neg += 1
    else: 
        count_zero += 1
print(count_pos)
print(count_neg)
print(count_zero)
```

Comment: when you use arr you are accessing the items themselves (the elements inside of arr) while with range() you are counting the index from 0 to the length of arr

Answer (score 1):

These are two different by meaning things

```
range(len(arr))
```

will return a list from 0 to `len(arr) - 1`

List is iterable so you can iterate over its elements

The default iteration construction is for loop

```
for i in <iterable>:
```

So in the first example you are iterating over

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

which was created by range()

In the second example you are iterating over

```
[-4, 3, -9, 0, 4, 1]
```

That is the difference

Comment: This has been a life changer to understand. Thank you!

Comment: `range(len(arr))` doesn't return a list: it returns a `range` object, which isn't the same thing. (`isinstance(range(10), list)` gives `False`)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your explanations!

So it turns out I wasn't aware that range() calls upon indexing, and if my function doesn't also index the variable ( arr[i] ) then I am just looping through and making calculations off the index numbers [0,1,2,3,4,5] instead of the actual values[-4, 3, -9, 0, 4, 1]. Good to know! Thanks everyone!